# count the frequency of data values from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x

`Category    freq
  a           2
  b           3
  s           2
  s           2
  b           3
  a           2
  b           3`

I have obtained this output after using pandas.value_counts() function but i just want the frequency array not the category one how can i get that,
I am using python 3.x for this.

Comment: Use `.values` on `value_counts()`.  Something like `df['x'].value_counts().values`

Comment: Thanks alot @SreeramTP for help that worked

Comment: I will post as answer. Accept if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.values` to get the counts as a numpy array.

You can do something like this

`df['x'].value_counts().values`